# Filter and Get Total of ng-show data only

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS, i have data in column `Quantity IN` and `Quantity EX` which displays data based on `inclusive` and `exclusive` check values.
The total i get, gets all of `Quantity IN` and `Quantity EX`. i want the total only of values which are shown on the table. refer my [plunk demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PO9C4VdfcvnIJY58bWlG?p=preview)

Total i got for `Quantity IN` is `127`
Total i expect for `Quantity IN` is `34`

**HTML**

```
<table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2"> S.No </th>
        <th rowspan="2"> fob </th>
        <th rowspan="2"> convertion rate </th>
        <th rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
        <th rowspan="2">inclusive</th>
        <th rowspan="2">exclusive</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Quantity IN</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Quantity EX</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=(sryarndebitnote)"> 
        <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td >{{mani.invoice_value_fob}}</td>
            <td >{{mani.conversion_rate }}</td>
            <td >{{mani.invoice_quantity}}</td>
             <td ><i class="fa servicetaxinclusive{{mani.service_tax}}"></i></td>
              <td ><i class="fa servicetaxexclusive{{mani.exclusive}}"></i></td>
               <td ><p ng-hide="mani.service_tax==false">{{(mani.invoice_quantity - mani.invoice_value_fob/100)}}</p></td>
               <td ><p ng-hide="mani.exclusive==false">{{(mani.invoice_quantity * mani.invoice_value_fob/100)}}</p></td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>sum</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate'}}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{resultValue | totalSumPriceQty:'invoice_quantity':'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | totalSumPriceQtytwo:'invoice_quantity':'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>
           </tr>
</table>
```

**Filters**

```
.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
return function (data, key) {
    debugger;
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
        return 0;        
    var sum = 0;

    angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
        sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
    });        
    return sum;
}
}).filter('totalSumPriceQty', function () {
return function (data, key1, key2) {        
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
        return 0;

    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
        sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) - parseInt(v[key2])/100);
    });
    return sum;
}
}).filter('totalSumPriceQtytwo', function () {
return function (data, key1, key2) {        
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
        return 0;

    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
        sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) * parseInt(v[key2])/100);
    });
    return sum;
}
})
```

[plunk demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PO9C4VdfcvnIJY58bWlG?p=preview)

Comment: try checking for the condition in your filter based on which you are hiding and showing the values in the view. Thats a possible workaround though not a proper solution. something like this  if(v['service_tax']==false){
            sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) - parseInt(v[key2])/100);
          }

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore the those rows which has service tax = false. Below changes will fix your problem I guess

```
filter('totalSumPriceQty', function() {
  return function(data, key1, key2, key3) {

    if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1) && angular.isUndefined(key2))
      return 0;

    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
      if (v[key3] == true) {
        sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) - parseInt(v[key2]) / 100);
      }
    });
    return sum;
  }
```

in Html

```
<td>{{resultValue | totalSumPriceQty:'invoice_quantity':'invoice_value_fob':'service_tax'}}</td>
```